# How to fix error System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat`5..ctor(System.String)'

Tags: ubuntu, f#-interactive

I have encountered an error using `printfn` function in F# Interactive in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

`` System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat`5..ctor(System.String)' ``

.NET core in 6.0.400 version is already installed on my machine

```
> dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.400 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

and after starting Interactive mode and typing simple code, I get the error.

```
> dotnet fsi
> printfn "Hello %s" "World";;
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfFormat`5..ctor(System.String)'.
Stopped due to error
```

I don't have much experience with Linux, so any suggestions on how to make it work are welcome.
This only happens in F# Interactive, so I'm assuming my setup is missing something, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Today, after updating .net core to the latest version `6.0.401`, this code started working correctly. Nevertheless I would be happy to understand what exactly happened ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the exact same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 with dotnet 6 and 7.

What has worked for me is to explicitly create a global.json file in the same folder with the current version you are running.

This is obviously redundant but resolves the issue, at least for me. Note that if dotnet upgrades you will also have to manually edit the global.json file

Get the dotnet version:

```
xxx@yyyy:~$ dotnet --info
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.402
```

Add the global.json file in the directory where you are running the script

```
{
    "sdk": {
    "version": "7.0.402"
    }
}
```